# Gulp watch and sass working but not working

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I've been toiling with this for a number of hours now and figured I best get some help as I'm going in circles.

I'm relatively new to using Gulp but quite excited to be doing so. I have a very simple gulpfile.js setup as below:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
    console.log("ran something");
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

This all executes just fine. However, my scss files only get compliled when I first execute gulp. The watch recognises all changes when I make them but no further compiles are made. It's almost like the file gets locked or cached or something strange after it is first initiated.

Here is cli output:

```
[15:04:04] Starting 'watch'...
[15:04:04] Finished 'watch' after 11 ms
[15:04:12] Starting 'sass'...
ran something
[15:04:12] Finished 'sass' after 8.17 ms
```

I'm running Windows 10 64bit and fresh install of gulp and dependencies as of today.

My primary editor is PhpStorm in which I've setup a configuration to run the gulp file. However, I've also tried in a basic text editor as well as running gulp directly from the node command prompt.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, although I'm not on Windows 10. What happens if you try running your `'sass'` task asynchronously by returning the stream, i.e., `return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss'))`?

Comment: Same result sorry. I have just reinstalled nodejs as well as I noticed I wasn't on the latest - still no luck. If I simply run the sass task directly it works fine. Could it somehow be a path issue when it is accessed via the watch task?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what it is, since I can't replicate it. But I'll give you a few suggestions since no one else seems to have any ideas. 1) Try using absolute paths rather than relative paths. 2) Try using using [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) rather than `gulp.watch()`. That's all I can think of for now.

Comment: Tried gulp-watch but same issue and absolute paths didn't seem to work either. I have noticed that the once I stop gulp from running it then will immediately update the file (from the scss task) to my latest changes. That help narrow anything down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears as though the issue wasn't an issue with gulp or any of the setup above. I noticed if I watched the files outside of all my editors that they were indeed being updated via gulp and it was just my editors that weren't responding until I stopped the gulp watch.

I trialled the latest version of PhpStorm 10 and it worked perfectly first time even though nothing else has changed. Must simply be a bug in version 8 seeming Gulp didn't exist back then.